# folder is created in eclipse home not in web application

Tags: java

I have create folder (i.e uploads ) in web application. I want to create one more folder inside "uploads" folder at runtime  depends one the username of user. for this i have write below code. This code is creating folder and file but the location is different that i expected.

the location that i am getting is in eclipse location not web application location

```
D:\PAST\RequiredPlugins\JUNO\eclipse\uploads\datto\adhar.PNG
```

then i am getting error in FileOutStream that "system can't find the location specified."

```
public String getFolderName(String folderName, MultipartFile uploadPhoto)
            throws ShareMeException {
        File uploadfFile = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("uploads\\" + folderName);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }

            uploadfFile = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()
                    + "\\"+uploadPhoto.getOriginalFilename());
            if (uploadfFile.exists()) {
                throw new ShareMeException(
                        "file already exist please rename it");
            } else {
                uploadfFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(uploadfFile);
                fout.write(uploadPhoto.getBytes());
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ShareMeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        return uploadfFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

i want to save uploaded file in web app "uploads" folder

Answer (score 1):

Your filename is not absolute: `uploads\folderName` is resolved against the current directory, which the Eclipse launcher sets to `JUNO\eclipse`.

You should introduce an application variable like `APP_HOME` and resolve any data directory (including `upload`) against this variable.

Also, I suggest not to name anything (neither files nor directories) on your filesystem after user-entered input: you are asking for troubles (unicode characters in the user name) and especially **security holes** (even in combination with the unicode thing). If you really want to use the filesystem, keep the filename anonymous (1.data, 2.data, ...) and keep metadata inside some database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something on below lines in your webapp:-

```
  String folderPath= request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
  File file = new File (folderPath+"upload");
  file.mkdir();
```

Comment: The folder is create is in unexpected path "workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ShareM‌​e\"